# Tagging in gogs not triggering build with drone.io

Tags: drone.io, gogs

I'm using drone 0.8.1 with gogs. When I commit to master a build is triggered. When I tag the repo in gogs, no build is triggered and no docker image built like I would expect. Here is my `.drone.yml` file:

`pipeline:
  docker:
    image: plugins/docker
    repo: larktech/mirror-repos
    default_tags: true
    when:
      event: [ push, tag ]`

Using gogs's release functionality, I tagged the repo `v1.0.1`, however no build ensued. Committing to master triggered the `latest` build as expected. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you enable repository hooks for tags in the repo settings?

Comment: I did not, I didn't realize there was a setting for that. I enabled hooks for `tag` and `deployment`. I also checked on the gogs side and checked 'Release' which added to the list of enabled events: `Create`, `Pull Request`, `Push`. I see that the webhook was triggered on the gogs side when I created a release. Drone did not attempt a build however. I have debug logging enabled on drone, however there is no message logged.

Answer (score 0):

Currently drone does not support the release event webhook, which is what is called when I tag a release in the gogs release tab.

With help from https://discourse.drone.io/t/tags-not-building-for-me/1236 I learned that pushing tags manually will trigger my build:

`git tag -a v1.0.6 -m 'another test'
git push origin v1.0.6`